# Фильтр по категориям Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Здравствуйте, подскажите как похожий фильтр написать на Vue.js?

Может есть пример?

```js
$('.filters a').on('click', function() {
  $('.filters li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active'); // выделяем выбранную категорию

  var cat = $(this).attr('data-filter'); // определяем категорию

  if (cat == 'all') { // если all
    $('.products li').show(); // отображаем все позиции
  } else { // если не all
    $('.products li').hide(); // скрываем все позиции
    $('.products li[data-filter="' + cat + '"]').show(); // и отображаем позиции из соответствующей категории
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filters li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.filters li.active a {
  color: #f00;
}

.products:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.products li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="active"><a data-filter="all">all</a></li>
  <li><a data-filter="cat1">cat1</a></li>
  <li><a data-filter="cat2">cat2</a></li>
  <li><a data-filter="cat3">cat3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="products">
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: function () {
    const cats = ['cat 1', 'cat 2', 'cat 3']
    return {
      picked: 'all',
      cats,
      items: _.map(Array(10), (v, i) => (
        { value: `value ${i}`, cat: cats[i%3] }
      ))
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredItems () {
      if (this.picked == 'all')
        return this.items
      else
        return _.filter(this.items, x => x.cat == this.picked)
    }
  }
})
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dakuenjery/pen/mxyvap?editors=1010)

Comment: Это поле только для ответов. Задайте новый [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Ознакомтесь [как задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Так я вроде как ответил. Только не заметил, что вопрос был задан 4 месяца назад)

Comment: напиши пояснения что у тебя в коде происходит